# Perform set operation difference on a list of tuples

Tags: python, set, set-difference

**I am trying to get the difference between 2 containers but the containers are in a weird structure so I dont know whats the best way to perform a difference on it.** One containers type and structure I cannot alter but the others I can(variable delims).

```
delims = ['on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or']
words = collections.Counter(s.split()).most_common()
# words results in [("the",2), ("a",9), ("diplomacy", 1)]

#I want to perform a 'difference' operation on words to remove all the delims words
descriptive_words = set(words) - set(delims)

# because of the unqiue structure of words(list of tuples) its hard to perform a difference
# on it. What would be the best way to perform a difference? Maybe...

delims = [('on',0),('with',0),('to',0),('and',0),('in',0),('the',0),('from',0),('or',0)]
words = collections.Counter(s.split()).most_common()
descriptive_words = set(words) - set(delims)

# Or maybe
words = collections.Counter(s.split()).most_common()
n_words = []
for w in words:
   n_words.append(w[0])
delims = ['on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or']
descriptive_words = set(n_words) - set(delims)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just modifying `words` by removing all the delimiters?

```
words = collections.Counter(s.split())
for delim in delims:
    del words[delim]
```

Comment: that looks efficient I think I'll use it but words is a list of tuples how can I say "words[delim]"?

Comment: @JakeM - apply it directly on the Counter object.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking words was the Counter object

Answer (score 1):

This I how I would do it:

```
delims = set(['on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or'])
# ...
descriptive_words = filter(lamdba x: x[0] not in delims, words)
```

Using the filter method. A viable alternative would be:

```
delims = set(['on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or'])
# ...
decsriptive_words = [ (word, count) for word,count in words if word not in delims ]
```

Making sure that the `delims` are in a set to allow for [O(1) lookup](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: the first method uses 'in', does that mean on each comparision we are iterating over the whole of delims?

Comment: not if they're a set or dict. O(1) lookup, [the docs say](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to do:

```
import collections

s = "the a a a a the a a a a a diplomacy"
delims = {'on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or'}
// For older versions of python without set literals:
// delims = set(['on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or'])
words = collections.Counter(s.split())

not_delims = {key: value for (key, value) in words.items() if key not in delims}
// For older versions of python without dict comprehensions:
// not_delims = dict(((key, value) for (key, value) in words.items() if key not in delims))
```

Which gives us:

```
{'a': 9, 'diplomacy': 1}
```

An alternative option is to do it pre-emptively:

```
import collections

s = "the a a a a the a a a a a diplomacy"
delims = {'on','with','to','and','in','the','from','or'}
counted_words = collections.Counter((word for word in s.split() if word not in delims))
```

Here you apply the filtering on the list of words before you give it to the counter, and this gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating through it anyway why bother converting them to sets?

```
dwords = [delim[0] for delim in delims]
words  = [word for word in words if word[0] not in dwords]
```

Comment: @Rob Young yeah I am trying to avoid iterating over them for efficiency. Any solution that doesn't iterate is best I think

Comment: Bad idea. It would be O(n^2), wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you can use **lambda** functions

```
filter(lambda word: word[0] not in delim, words)
```

Comment: filter+lambda is less readable than a list comprehension, and the list comprehension can [often be faster](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops).

Comment: Secondly, this is still doing O(n^2) since delims is a list.